# animate fixed bottom bar to appear on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i have a bar that is fixed to the bottom of the browser.  i want to make the bar displayed as 'none', so that when a user hovers over the bar it is displayed until they hover out.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>test</title>
<style>
html {
background: #34495e;
}
#pagebottom {
width: 92%;
height: 20px;
background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.80);
margin-left: 4%;
margin-right: 4%;
bottom: 0;
position: fixed;
color: #3498db;
text-align: center;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="pagebottom">
random text
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can accomplish this with CSS. No JavaScript needed.:

```
#pagebottom {
    opacity: 0;
    width: 92%;
    height: 20px;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.80);
    margin-left: 4%;
    margin-right: 4%;
    bottom: 0;
    position: fixed;
    color: #3498db;
    text-align: center;
}

#pagebottom:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

try this css solution

```
#pagebottom {
    width: 92%;
    height: 20px;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.80);
    margin-left: 4%;
    margin-right: 4%;
    bottom: 0;
    position: fixed;
    color: #3498db;
    text-align: center;
    opacity:0;        
}
#pagebottom:hover{
    opacity:1;
    transition:all .5s linear;
}
```

Comment: Man, can't believe I skipped straight to jQuery without even thinking of this simple solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

1) `css()` to set the opacity of your div:

2) `hover()` to keep track of when the mouse pointer enters and leaves your div

3) `animate()` to apply `fadeIn()` and `fadeOut` animation when changing the opacity

```
$('#pagebottom').css('opacity','0');

$( "#pagebottom" ).hover(
  function() {
    $('#pagebottom').stop().animate({opacity: 1}, 500);
  }, function() {
    $('#pagebottom').stop().animate({opacity: 0}, 500);
  }
);
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rkW2p/1/)**

Comment: i can't believe i didn't think of the opacity. i was instead messing with jquery which i know nothing about.  thanks all, i really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT** This is a jQuery solution.  There are some great CSS only solutions above.

---

You can't display your div as `none`, as it will have no width or height, and therefore be un-hoverable.  However, you can use the `opacity` attribute, and modify the footer's CSS accordingly.

[Take a look at this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/piedoom/RLnZK/)

Here are the changes I made:

I added `opacity: 0;` to the #pagebottom CSS so it is invisible by default.

I added the following jQuery:

```
$('#pagebottom').mouseenter(function(){
    $('#pagebottom').css('opacity','1');
});

$('#pagebottom').mouseleave(function(){
    $('#pagebottom').css('opacity','0');
});
```

This code waits until the mouse enters the div area, and sets the opacity to 1.  When the mouse leaves, it sets the opacity to 0 again, making the element invisible.

If you want a nice tradition so the div fades in and out, you can use [CSS transitions](http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/transitions/) or a jQuery plugin like [Transit](http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/), or even the animate feature that Felix describes in his answer.